# Getting started with Cloud Functions for Firebase and Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Can anyone please give me pointers for getting Firestore working with Cloud Functions.

I am trying to follow the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions

Using `firebase deploy --only functions:_onFirestoreWrite_notifications`

I get the message: HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports._onFirestoreWrite_notifications = functions.firestore
  .document('_notifications')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

  //..

  });
```

Comment: Where is your problem?
From my point of view, next step would be deployment, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#deploy-and-executeaddmessage

Comment: Firebase deploy errors so I guess I am missing somthing before "exports." that allows Firestore to run

Comment: Please update your question with the command you are running and the corresponding error message from "firebase deploy ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update following OP's comment below: apparently using underscores in the Cloud Function name is causing an issue*.

With the `onWrite()` trigger you are going to trigger an event for any change to a specific **document**. Documents in Firestore are stored within **collections**, therefore you need to pass the **full path of the document** to the `document()` method, as follows:

```
exports.onFirestoreWriteNotifications = functions.firestore
  .document('collection/_notifications')  //Note the addition of the collection
  .onWrite()
```

---

In addition, note that you don't need to do

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();
```

since, in your Cloud Functions, you will use the [Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin?authuser=0) to interact with Firestore.

So doing

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

is sufficient as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) (Node.js tab).

Then you will call the Firestore database with `admin.firestore()`, like for example, `admin.firestore().collection('_hello').add({...})`

---

In addition, note that you have to return the Promises returned by the asynchronous tasks.

If I refer to your initial code (before your edit)

```
exports._onFirestoreWrite_notifications = functions.firestore
  .document('collection/_notifications')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

    db.firestore//.collection('_hello').add({
      text: "itworks",
      from: "onWrite"
    });

  });
```

you need to do

```
return admin.firestore().collection('_hello').add({
  text: "itworks",
  from: "onWrite"
});
//!!! Note the return (and the use of admin.firestore() )
```

**This is an important point** and is very well explained in the three videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Hi, thanks for picking that up but its the functions.firestore that is not working, I have tried different combinations before posting and cannot get it working

Comment: Ok,now I see the problem: you need to define your doc with the parent collection, like exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
    .document('collection_name/_notifications'')

Comment: Hi, found the issue... apparently underscores are causing the issue in firebase functions so my function name "_onFirestoreWrite_notifications"  works if I renamed it to "onFirestoreWriteNotifications"

Comment: Good to hear that @PHILLBOOTH! But I still think you need to add the collection in the document path, as explained in the answer.

Comment: Agreed .document('_notifications/{userID}')